# Proving that ($\mathbb{Z}$, $\prec$) is a well order

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let´s define the following relation between integers: let´s say that for n and m in $\mathbb{Z}$, $n\prec m$ is true if and only if one of the following conditions is true :

1) $0 \leqslant n\leqslant m$ or

2) $0 \leqslant n $ and $m< 0$ or

3) $n< 0$, $m< 0$, and $\left | n \right | \leqslant \left | m \right |$

Assuming that the order $\prec$ is a linear order, prove that the structure ($\mathbb{Z}$, $\prec$) is a  well order. That is, prove that every non empty subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ has a minimum element in the order of $\prec$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So the nonnegative integers are ordered as usual, the negative integers are ordered by increasing absolute value, and all negative integers come after all positive integers?

If so, then split it into the cases based on whetehr the nonempty subset contains a nonnegative integer or not.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Consider $A\subseteq\Bbb Z$ non-empty. If $A\cap\Bbb N\neq\varnothing$, find a minimal element. Otherwise, consider $\{|m|:m\in A\}$.